# Unable to Fetch video preview along with Image preview together

Tags: javascript, html

I m trying to have an image preview and video preview on a single page.

**Here's the code :**

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>

<ul class="d-flex flex-wrap align-items-center list-inline m-0 p-0">
    <li class="col-md-6 mb-3">
        <div class="iq-bg-primary rounded p-2 pointer mr-3">
             <img src="images/small/07.png" alt="icon" class="img-fluid">
             <label style="margin-left:20px;" for="image">Post a Photo</label>
             <input id="image" type="file" name="image" style="display: none;">
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="col-md-6 mb-3">
        <div class="iq-bg-primary rounded p-2 pointer mr-3">
             <img src="images/small/13.png" alt="icon" class="img-fluid">
             <label style="margin-left:20px;" for="image">Post a Video</label>
             <input id="video" type="file" name="video" style="display: none;">
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>



<div>
    <img id="blah">
    
    <video >
         <source id="blahh" src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
         <source id="blahh" src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
           Your browser does not support the video tag.
    </video>
</div>



<!-- for image preview -->          
<script>
    $('#image').change(function(){
  if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (e) {
        selectedImage = e.target.result;
        $('#blah').attr('src', selectedImage);
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
  }
});
</script>
 <!-- End image preview -->     
 



 <!-- for video preview -->          
<script>
    $('#video').change(function(){
  if (this.files && this.files[1]) {
    var Vreader = new FileReader();
    Vreader.onload = function (e) {
        selectedVideo = e.target.result;
        $('#blahh').attr('src', selectedVideo);
    };
    Vreader.readAsDataURL(this.files[1]);
  }
});
</script>
 <!-- End video preview -->
```

The image preview script is working well, But the video preview doesn't.
It simply returns to image preview with unable to preview the selected video in the image tag.

I think I might have messed up with the array over this. files, but open to suggestions.